# how can I close a command prompt window

Tags: command-line

I want to close my command prompt window by pressing a key.How should I code this?

```
System.out.println("Press 1 to change student information 2 to exit  ");
```

I want to close it by pressing 2.Please help me I'm a beginner.

Comment: You should mention what operating system and give more details. Also, you need to do research prior to just asking questions that are answered many times already.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a windows command prompt?

Send the 'exit' command to the console.
In what language are you programming? C++ ? 
You may want to try `system ("exit");` located in `#include <stdlib.h>`

This may actually also close your program but i am not sure.
If you dont want the console to ever open you may want to explore the linker options of your IDE and just dont link the console to the program.

Comment: yeah it's a windows command prompt and I'm using java.Is this work in java also?

Comment: I am not sure how that would work in java. But essentially you should be able to not start the console there as well. Consider adding the tag java to your question.